# How to set image preview on the Sony A7Riii

Tags: camera-settings, sony, preview, sony-a7ii

I'm used to shooting Nikon, where when you take a photo it shows a preview of the image on the main screen for a few seconds, or until you soft tap the shutter again. Is there a way to implement this in the Sony A7Riii? Right now it goes right back into live view immediately, without a preview of the image I just took.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you are seeking is **Auto Review**. It is located in the menu under Display/Auto Review. From page 69 of the manual ([pdf](http://www.sony-asia.com/electronics/support/res/manuals/4728/2b3f52f7b398c5f1ca1e1112d1d449ee/47287791M.pdf)):

> Auto Review: Sets auto review to display the captured image after shooting.